# Anyone knows of a salesforce release calendar out there that we can import into our calendar app?

Tags: calendar, release

I want to add the release dates into my own/org calendar.

Does anyone know of a public ical or any other format we can use?

Answer (score 1):

The help section of [status.salesforce.com](https://status.salesforce.com/) provides Swagger docs about [public APIs](https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/).

Here is the link to documentation to retrieve maintenance infos: https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/#/maintenances/getMaintenances

You could call these APIs and retrieve the data into your org calendar.

(I have not tried calling these APIs, but it might be worth checking out)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK nothing publicly available. Just saw this idea, but still have few votes:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXDGUA3/publish-the-salesforce-release-calendar-as-an-ical-feed?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null